# Clone a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Is there any way to clone a list in Haskell? I can't find any documentation on this or anything on SO. If there isn't can someone suggest a simple implementation on how to do so?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Haskell values are immutable. "Modifying" a list is just transforming it into a new list; the original list is never changed. So, since lists can't change in the first place, there's no need to clone them; you can just reuse the original list.

Answer (score 7):

Like almost every data type in Haskell, lists are immutable, so there is no need to copy them.